# if condition in javascript using variables

Tags: javascript, if-statement

The problem with this code is when I'm executing the if condition. The condition only works if i am using `if (pixel.getx() <=100)` but does not work for a `var x = pixel.getX() & if (x <= 100)`. Can someone tell me why?

```
var image = new SimpleImage (200,200);
print (image);

for (var pixel of image.values())
var x = pixel.getX();
var y = pixel.getY()

if (x <= 100 && y <= 100)

{
pixel.setRed(255);
pixel.setBlue(0);
pixel.setGreen(0);  
}

else if (x > 100)
{
pixel.setBlue(255);
pixel.setGreen(0);
pixel.setRed(0);
}   
print (image);
```

Comment: What is `SimpleImage`? `getx` and `getX` are two different methods. Is that the issue? Or just a typo in the question?

Comment: Your `for (var pixel of image.values())` loop isn't using `{` braces `}` and therefore operates only on the next statement after it, `var x = pixel.getX();` The rest of your code, including the `if` statement, is not part of the loop.

Comment: `var x = pixel.getX() & if (x <= 100)` is not valid syntax, so that's an issue

Answer (score 2):

your `for` loop is missing `{}`.
all it does the way you have it in your example is 
executing `var x = pixel.getX();` as many times as there are `image.values()`

if you need to repeat a multi line block of code within a for loop it needs to be inside `{}`

if you are repeating one statement - you don't need `{}` - that's why it worked when you had `if (pixel.getX() <= 100) {...}`

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop is missing the braces `{ }` and that's why its not working.

Modified code,

```
var image = new SimpleImage (200,200);
print (image);

for (var pixel of image.values()) {
    var x = pixel.getX();
    var y = pixel.getY()

    if (x <= 100 && y <= 100) {
        pixel.setRed(255);
        pixel.setBlue(0);
        pixel.setGreen(0);  
    } else if (x > 100) {
        pixel.setBlue(255);
        pixel.setGreen(0);
        pixel.setRed(0);
    }   

    print (image);
}
```